# JSF and 2 backendbean calls that should be synchronous

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, xhtml, richfaces

I have code similar to that:

```
<a4j:commandButton
    onclick="showProcessingPanel(); prepareOperation()"
    oncomplete="#{!operationBean.operationPrepared ? 'showNoOperationAvailable()':'startOperation()'}; hideProcessingPanel()">
```

Now, the prepareOperation is a javascript call which gives backendBean some data and then fires an method on it.

ShowProcessingPanel shows a panel which informs the user that some operation is ongoing and has no data/state.

OperationPrepared property in the operationBean is updated only AFTER backends bean method from prepareOperation() method completes, it's false by default.

Now my problem is that onclick and oncomplete methods happen almost simultaneously, so sometimes even though prepareOperation sets the operationPrepared to true, the startOperation is not invoked becuase oncomplete was triggered earlier than prepareOperation was changed.

How to modify it so that it works as intented?

Comment: That should already be the default behavior. Cause of your problem is not visible in the information provided so far.

Comment: The backendbean call in "prepareOperation()" returns void, so it completes immediately (as well as the onclick method) - however it updates the operationBean.operationPrepared property after it has done all of the processing.

Comment: Async/sync behavior has nothing to do with the return type. Perhaps you're actually spawning a separate thread in the method itself?

Comment: No, the backendbean does not spawn a separate thread. For more context prepareOperation() is an a4j:j4Function which has parameter "action" which is the first backendBean call.

Comment: So you basically want to run `oncomplete` code on complete of *that* `a4j:jsFunction` instead? Just move the `oncomplete` attribute to it. It indeed spawns a separate (ajax) request, so effectively you're *actually* spawning a separate thread in server. Nonetheless, this construct is weird. You'd perhaps better merge the two ajax requests into a single ajax request, e.g. move `action` of the `a4j:jsFunction` into `a4j:commandButton` and then get rid of `prepareOperation()` in `onclick`.

Comment: Okay, so the fact that each a4j component spawns their own thread during ajax request would explain why this works as it works. I'll try to do as you suggest, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately oncomplete and action in the same a4j jsfunction happen at the same time.

Comment: @PlsqlNo the value of oncomplete is resolved after action (and also before but that will be overwritten by the second resolution).